# Best way to scale layout styles in Android?

Tags: android, string, layout, styles, scale

I've run into a dilemma when working with apps that should support a large range of screen sizes. What is the best way to scale attributes like text size, width and height via styles?
Optimally, I would love a setup like this:

```
layout.xml:
  <YourView style="@style/Footer"/>

styles.xml:
  <style name="Footer"> 
    <item name="android:layout_height">@string/FooterHeight</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_footer</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom</item>
  </style>

values/layout_vals.xml:
  <string name="FooterHeight">50dp</string>

values-sw600dp/layout_vals.xml:
  <string name="FooterHeight">80dp</string>
```

Then, in order to change the height of a View, all one would have to do is create a new folder with the target min width and edit the values of *layout_vals.xml*, and leave all the extraneous junk about width, gravity, background etc alone, leaving for a much cleaner setup and easier editing.

However, I've tried and found out that this exact setup doesn't work. For now, I just copy the entire styles.xml into the different 'layout-swXXdp' folders and swap out values. Does anyone have suggestions as to another method of project setup that is comparable to or, better yet, even *better* than this? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of string, use the @[dimen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) resource - I think its exactly what you're looking for (except it would go into res/values-sw600dp)